# How to execute a Gradle task before subprojects are evaluated

Tags: java, android, cordova, build, gradle

I've set up a Gradle task to auto generate one of the subprojects of my Gradle build on which another depends (reason for doing this: long story involving Apache Cordova!). So the root build.gradle contains this autogenerate task that creates a "CordovaLib" sub project.  The build.gradle in the other sub project (that isn't autogenerated) depends on CordovaLib:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':CordovaLib')
}
```

Is there a way to execute the autogenerate task before the non-generated subproject's build.gradle is evaluated (specifically the above line)? I'm using Gradle 1.11 on JDK 1.7 and as it currently stands I can't even run `gradle tasks` without it failing due to the missing project.

Comment: There is no way to execute tasks in the configuration phase of a build. Why do you think it's necessary? What *exactly* do you mean by "auto generate one of the suprojects"? You'd have to provide more details.

Comment: To craft Android plugins for Apache Cordova you need to use Cordova to generate a `CordovaLib` project on which you can depend for the Cordova-specific stuff.  Rather than check in this auto-generated code to source control I'd like to be able to generate it via Gradle.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the generation needs to happen at configuration time (i.e. "before subprojects are evaluated"). Why can't it be done by a regular Gradle task? What exactly do you mean by "before subprojects are evaluated"?

Comment: Hmmm because I want to set up the plugin project to depend on this CordovaLib project in Gradle, is this a silly idea?

Comment: You'd have to explain in much more detail (as part of your question).

Comment: Ok have tried to do so, hope that's clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to execute a task before build files have been evaluated, at least not without complications such as one build executing another build using a `GradleBuild` task. You are likely better off checking the generated project in to source control, or finding a solution that doesn't involve generating build scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use init script to gradle to achieve this.

https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/init_scripts.html